# Simulate data based on linear regression and R squared

Tags: r, regression, predictive-models, prediction, r-squared

I have a small data set of 10 x,y points from which I can derive a simple linear regression.

I'm looking to use this data set as a basis to simulate / predict additional "y" points as I have a much larger separate data set of "x" points.

I'm not sure what is the best way to do this - I have some code below as a trial, but this generally seems to produce data sets that have materially worse R-squared values.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated - my sample code below:

```
# Initial empty df
MG_ADL_IgG_df <- data.frame(IgG_reduction = c(), MG_ADL = c())


for (temp_i in 1:100) {

  #creates a linear model between MG-ADL and IgG reduction
  mg_adl_model <- lm(MG_ADL_IgG_correl$`MG-ADL_delta_baseline` ~ MG_ADL_IgG_correl$IgG_reduction)

  plot(MG_ADL_IgG_correl$`MG-ADL_delta_baseline` ~ MG_ADL_IgG_correl$IgG_reduction)

  abline(mg_adl_model)

  # takes residuals from linear model
  resid <- residuals(mg_adl_model)

  #generates predicted values
  pred_values <- predict(mg_adl_model)

  #uniformly at random generates risduals based on range of residuals
  sim_err <- runif(length(pred_values), min = min(resid), max = max(resid))

  sim_values <- c()

  # placeholder for what would be new "x" points
  rand_values <- runif(length(pred_values), 0, 1)

  #generate simulated / predicted "y" values
  for (i in 1:length(rand_values)) {
    sim_values[i] <- (pred_values[i] + sim_err[i])
  }

  #add points to plot
  points(rand_values, sim_values, pch=23, col="green")

  #create new data set of "x" and "y" points
  temp_df <- data.frame(IgG_reduction = rand_values, MG_ADL = sim_values)

  #generate temp linear reg model to test R-squared value
  temp_lm <- lm(temp_df$IgG_reduction ~ temp_df$MG_ADL)

  r_sqr <- summary(temp_lm)$r.squared

  if (r_sqr >= 0.25 & r_sqr <= 0.35) {
    MG_ADL_IgG_df <- rbind(MG_ADL_IgG_df, temp_df)

  }
}

temp_lm <- lm(MG_ADL_IgG_df$IgG_reduction ~ MG_ADL_IgG_df$MG_ADL)

summary(temp_lm)$r.squared
```

Comment: Do you expect causal relationship?

Comment: Yes, based on what the data are it is expected that the two should have a reasonable correlation.

Comment: No, not correlation, the causality.

Comment: Yes, this is related to a biological pathway and a clinical metric - a reduction in one should generally cause a reduction in the other but with some degree of variability.

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with these simulated values?

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is bootstrapping. Estimate regression, get the residuals.

Get an empirical cdf of x. Then use inverse of it to generate new x set.

Plug new x into the regression model and add bootstrapped residuals

That was if you think x causes y. If there’s no causality then it’s easier. Get eCDFs of x and y. Then estimate correlation of eCDF outputs if x and y. Then generate univariate independent variables u and v with rand(). Finally create new set where X is inverse eCDF of u, Y is inverse eCDF of $u \rho + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}$

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a bit of R code or references - I'm more well versed in Python, but having to do this in R, still learning - thank you!

Comment: I can but wouldn’t then this be a coding question and off topic?

Comment: Sry I don't post much here - if I put on StackOverflow can you help me out there? What's the appropriate forum to post for coding input?

Comment: I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012346/simulate-data-based-on-linear-regression-and-r-squared

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to first use R's predict function to first generate Prediction intervals or Confidence intervals around the independent values.

Read this link for more info.
[R prediction info](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/40-regression-analysis/166-predict-in-r-model-predictions-and-confidence-intervals/)

The next step is to use those intervals to generate possible values with a random number generator scaled appropriately for those values.